# How to query JIRA issues based on the issue number in an excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, api, jira

On windows 10 I want to query JIRA data within an excel (to extract single elements, like the "summary", the "status", the "assignee" etc.) for a bunch of issues I list in the excel itself (i.e. the issue names):

[image]

To do so I have been trying to add the external source via

```
Get Data -> From Other sources -> From Web
```

[image]

and added the base URL and the authorization header, and I tried to add "parts" for the URL as each issue has its own URL

```
https://myjira.com/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-1
https://myjira.com/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-2
https://myjira.com/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-42
```

I tried as follows:

[image]

but instead adding the content of the cell it is literally adding the string like "B3" to the URL and not the strings I have defined in the excel table ("TEST-1, TEST-2", ...).

How to add/configure excel so it can query the issue ID that is listed e.g. in call "A2" (content: "TEST-1") in order to extract the summary of this ticket in cell "B2" (so that the cell "B2" contains automatically the summary of the ticket "TEST-1")?

Comment: See [this method](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/jira-odbc-excel-query.rst) that uses ODBC.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for this hint, but I cannot see the "RSSBus Salesforce Source x64". I can only choose between "New Data Source", "dBASE Files", "Excel Files" and "MS Access Database"

Comment: You might need the Jira ODBC Driver, but if you don't have it already then I can't advise you to buy this costly driver.

Comment: You have to use the advance editor of power query to get a cell reference into your web part, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74122306/referencing-a-cell-value-as-a-parameter-in-the-url-in-excels-data-from-web-func

Comment: it seems like there is an official JIRA connector for execl: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221301/jira-cloud-for-excel-official?tab=overview&hosting=cloud

Comment: Maybe Power Query is a better solution for this. Dunno if it can work with inputting an issue list in Excel though.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to dynamically incorporate JIRA in Excel is to access
the JIRA data via ODBC. A more static method would be to use the JIRA
software to export the data, perhaps as a CSV file that Excel can use.

Unfortunately accessing JIRA via ODBC requires a costly commercial driver.

You may use these :

- [Jira ODBC Driver](https://www.cdata.com/drivers/jira/odbc/)
- [Jira Cloud for Excel](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1221301/jira-cloud-for-excel-official?tab=overview&hosting=cloud)
  (free but additional purchase may be required)

For using the JIRA ODBC source, see the article
[Using Microsoft Query in Excel to Connect to Jira](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/jira-odbc-excel-query.rst).